# Monitoring and controlling ActiveMQ using RHQ 4.7

Tags: monitoring, activemq-classic, rhq

I am trying to monitor and control an ActiveMQ  based application, along with some Jboss AS7 applications. I have downloaded RHQ 4.7 but couldn’t find any ActiveMQ plug-in support. While searching through I came across the , [rhq-plugin Git hub repository](https://github.com/rafachies/rhq-plugins), but this plug-in seems to be work in progress, and also found this [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=535577) entry.

Could you please let me know, Is there any plug-in available to manage ActiveMQ using RHQ? 
If not could you please guide me to develop one ActiveMQ plug-in

Answer (score 3):

The RHQ team does not maintain an ActiveMQ plugin. The FuseSource team may have one. Chat with them on IRC or mailing list: http://fuse.fusesource.org/community.html

As for starting a new plugin, you may read the wiki doc:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Writing+Custom+Plugins

Best option would be to build on top of the JMX plugin IMO.

Feel free to ask any question on #rhq at Freenode or on the RHQ mailing lists or forum. We'll be glad to help.